# Truffle js test. Test not really testing

Tags: solidity, truffle

I have this tests that supposedly pass (in the terminal, I can see the checks). But they never actually run the code:

```
it("should add an exam to the exams list", () => {
        let hash_test = "9F86D081884C7D659A2FEAA0C55AD015A3BF4F1B2B0B822CD15D6C15B0F00A08";
        Exam.deployed()
            .then(instance => instance.addExam(hash_test, {from: accounts[0]}))
            .then(hash => {
                assert.equal(hash.valueOf(), hash_test, "Not returning the correct address");
                console.log("THIS");
            })
            .then(instance => instance.isOwner(hash_test, {from: accounts[0]}))
            .then(isOwner => {
                assert.equal(isOwner, "true", "Not recognizing hash correctly");
                assert.equal("true", "false", "NOT WORKING AT ALL");
            })
            .then(instance => instance.isOwner("THISISWRONG", {from: accounts[0]}))
            .then(isOwner => {
                assert.equal(isOwner, "false", "Not recognizing hash correctly")
            });
    });
```

As you can see, there is an `assert.equal("true", "false"` . But I still get the checks as if it passed:

> ## Compiling your contracts...
>
> > Compiling ./contracts/Exams.sol
>
> Contract: Exams
>       ✓ should pass this test
>       ✓ should add an exam to the exams list
>       ✓ Should add an student address to the people that passed the exam
>
> 3 passing (68ms)

I don't know what could be wrong, my code is almost the same as the one in the official site.

Answer (score 1):

Since this part doesn't return anything:

```
.then(hash => {
    assert.equal(hash.valueOf(), hash_test, "Not returning the correct address");
    console.log("THIS");
})
```

No other `then` is executed passed this point, and the `it` completes successfully.

I'm assuming that you have two additional `it`s in your test, hence the printout `3 passing`.

Aside from that, I recommend using the `async`/`await` scheme, which yields a much cleaner code while achieving the exact same goal:

```
it("should add an exam to the exams list", async function() {
    const hash_test = "9F86D081884C7D659A2FEAA0C55AD015A3BF4F1B2B0B822CD15D6C15B0F00A08";
    const instance = await Exam.deployed(); // maybe `await` isn't needed here
    const hash = await instance.addExam(hash_test, {from: accounts[0]});
    assert.equal(hash.valueOf(), hash_test, "Not returning the correct address");
    const isOwner = await instance.isOwner(hash_test, {from: accounts[0]});
    assert.equal(isOwner, true, "Not recognizing hash correctly");
    const isNotOwner = await instance.isOwner("THISISWRONG", {from: accounts[0]});
    assert.equal(isNotOwner, false, "Not recognizing hash correctly")
});
```

Note that `isOwner` should be compared to `true`/`false` and not to `"true"`/`"false"`, because web3.js returns Boolean values as Boolean and not as String.

Also, as you've already been explained on several previous questions of yours, because function `addExam` changes the state of the contract on the blockchain, when you call it from the off-chain (e.g., a web3.js script), you get back a receipt object, and not the actual value which your function returns (this one is available only when you call the function from the on-chain, i.e., from this contract or from another contract).

Thus, the statement `assert.equal(hash.valueOf(), hash_test)` is prone to failure.